# How to hit jsp from java class

Tags: java, jsp

How to hit jsp from java class without using servlet?
i need parameter from client computer to server( tomcat) then insert into DB.

Below is my java class coding:

```
public void callJSP(String fullContent) {

    // convert String into InputStream
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(fullContent.getBytes());
    InputStreamReader isr;
    BufferedReader br;
    String line;
    URL url;
    URLConnection connection;
    ObjectOutputStream output;
    ObjectInputStream input;
    try {
        isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        line = br.readLine();
        url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/WebContent/FeedIssueToDB.jsp");
        connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        output.writeObject(line);
        output.close();
        /*input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        input.readObject();
        input.close();*/
        // TODO do your stuff here
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

this is JSP:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" language="java" import="java.sql.*" errorPage=""%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
<%
String fullContent= request.getParameter("line");
System.out.println("full content -"+fullContent);

  %>
  <%

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.55:1433/RTDATA_TT", "sa", "dominorich");
PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO SummaryFeedIssue(\"DateTimeIssue\", \"Source\", \"ServerIP\", \"Keywords\",\"Remarks\") VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");

StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(fullContent, "|");
String dateTime="";
String source="";
String serverIP="";
String keywords="";
String remarks="";
while (st1.hasMoreTokens()) {
    dateTime = st1.nextToken();
    source = st1.nextToken();
    serverIP = st1.nextToken();
    keywords = st1.nextToken();
    remarks = st1.nextToken();
 ps.setString(1,dateTime );
 ps.setString(2,source );
 ps.setString(3,serverIP );
 ps.setString(4,keywords );
 ps.setString(5,remarks );

ps.execute();
conn.close();

}

%>
```

After run the application, it no action.Any wrong for my coding?

Comment: please dont write business logic  jsp  page.

Answer (score 1):

You should not write you business logic in the JSPs, rather you should have a manager or a helper class having the business logic and call their methods in the JSPs.

But,

To run your code, you should change the line

```
url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/WebContent/FeedIssueToDB.jsp");
```

to

```
url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/WebContent/FeedIssueToDB.jsp?line="+line);
```

and no need to write the line to output stream.

Passing the line as parameter should do the work which you are intended to do.

Comment: please kindly advice what is a manager or a helper class having the business logic..got example? Sorry i'm new in this case.

Comment: Manager class just means writing your business in other class class and instantiate that in JSPs and call there methods to perform operations.

Comment: @SharonWong just don't write ANY Java code in your JSP, use taglets and JSTL instead and call Java classes that exist outside your page. The JSP itself should ONLY display data and forward requests to the Java code running behind it.

Comment: Manager class just means writing your business in other class class and instantiate that in JSPs and call there methods to perform operations. In your case writing the complete code related to get connection and saving the data in database (let say you create a save(inputData) method) in a class and create its object in JSP and call its "new YourClass().save(fullContent)". Let me know if you get it